# deploy django application on apache server

Tags: django, deployment, apache2

I'm new to django and deploying apps. I tried to follow [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-14-04) tutorial. Everything worked great except that by the end, instead of the django app I got the depault apache2 page. (If it's matter, I work on ubuntu).

/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:8079>


    Alias /static /home/or/myproject/static
    <Directory /home/or/myproject/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/or/myproject/myproject/>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-path=/home/or/myproject/ python-home=/home/or/myproject/myprojectenv
    WSGIProcessGroup myproject
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/or/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py

</VirtualHost>
```

Any suggestions? maybe firewall or something? I'm pretty lost...

```
  [1]: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-14-04
```

Comment: did you restart the `apache`?

Comment: @AgamBanga yes..

Comment: can you paste your `000-default.conf` file?

Comment: @AgamBanga Thank you for trying to help. Anyway, I pasted it but for some reason it doesn't show the <VirtualHost *:80> by the beginning and </VirtualHost> by the end...

Comment: are the paths correct in `<Directory /home/user/myproject/myproject>` & other. it seems you have copied exactly from the tutorial. you need to update the path according to your project

Comment: @AgamBanga the paths are as should (they are correct according to my project)

Comment: you have a `user` folder in your ubuntu home directory? Generally its some other name

Comment: I'm sorry.. I edited it. but still not working

Comment: and you have a project named `myproject` as well? can you paste the snapshot of the directory structure of your project. Also when you restart the apache, does it throw some error?

Comment: What you provided was using port 8079. Is that what you really meant? Your comment above suggests you expected it to be port 80. What URL are you using to access it? Are you explicitly using port 8079?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm not sure what went wrong but I used [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VNBpdT0N8hw) tutorial and it works great (except that I edited '000-default' file instead of 'default' file.